# Proving a space is a subspace

Tags: linear-algebra

I've been given a list of spaces and asked to see if they are subspaces R<sup>2</sup>

Here's one thats giving me trouble
$$\begin{pmatrix}
x\\
y\end{pmatrix}: x^2 = -y^2$$

I understand to prove its a valid subspace, it needs to be closed under addition and scalar mulitpltication.

However after generating these vectors:

$$V=\begin{pmatrix}
a\\
b\end{pmatrix}, W=\begin{pmatrix}
c\\
d\end{pmatrix} $$

I cant seem to add the vectors in a way that will satisfyingly prove anything.

Given X<sup>2</sup>+Y<sup>2</sup> = 0

I know (a + c)<sup>2</sup> + (b + d)<sup>2</sup> = 0

But expanding that out seems to get me nowhere. I'm thinking im missing something very obvious here.

Comment: You are missing something. Can you find two explicit vectors that belong to that space?

Answer (score 1):

The only vector $\begin{pmatrix} x\\y \end{pmatrix}$ that satisfy $x^2+y^2=0$ is the zero vector. So, the subset 
$$\left \{ \begin{pmatrix} 0\\0 \end{pmatrix} \right\}$$
of $\Bbb R^2$ is a valid vector subspace.

Comment: Maybe i over complicated this based on a previous problem. I was given X^2 - Y^2 = 0, that same logic doesnt apply in that case?

Comment: In this case, the vectors $\begin{pmatrix} 1\\1 \end{pmatrix}$ and $\begin{pmatrix} 1\\-1 \end{pmatrix}$ belongs to the subset $$\left\{ \begin{pmatrix} x\\y \end{pmatrix} \in \mathbb R^2:\, x^2-y^2=0 \right\}$$ but $\begin{pmatrix} 1\\1 \end{pmatrix} + \begin{pmatrix} 1\\-1 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 2\\0 \end{pmatrix}$ doesn't.

Comment: Ahhh, i think i see.

Comment: Sorry, I hadn't finished writing my comment.